# JS Multiple Nested Try...Catch Blocks

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

I have a function which needs to perform multiple promises in a strict order, and if any one were to fail, the whole function needs to error out. I'm understanding that I should use a Try...Catch block to catch any exceptions which get thrown.

Currently, I am using a nested try...catch like:

```
try {
  try {
    code1()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Inner 1 ", err)
    throw err
  }

  try {
    code2()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Inner 2 ", err)
    throw err
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Outer", err)
} finally {
  console.log("Full Success")
}
```

The intention here is that if either `code1()` or `code2()` were to fail, the outer `catch` would trigger. If both `code1` and `code2` were to success, the outer `finally` block would trigger.

However, it seems, right now, no matter if `code1` or `code2` succeed, the outer `finally` is always being trigger in addition to the associated inner `catch` statements.

Is there any way to get the outer `catch` to trigger?

Comment: `finally` executes no matter what happens inside.

Comment: @Barmar Oh heck... my readings of the docs made me believe it only executed on success...

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#syntax): Statements that are executed after the try statement completes. These statements execute regardless of whether an exception was thrown or caught.

Comment: @Barmer Yep, realized my mistake after re-reading. I stopped at the first sentence...

Comment: Python has what you wanted in its `else:` block.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, thanks to @Barmar 's comment, the `finally` block will always execute, that's why my code was always throwing the `finally`. Instead, I moved the "full success" *into* the outer try block.

```
try {
  try {
    code1()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Inner 1 ", err)
    throw err
  }

  try {
    code2()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Inner 2 ", err)
    throw err
  }

  console.log("Full Success")
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Outer", err)
}
```

Now, it appears to be working as intended.